# How do I display Day of Week and vary responses by days?

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a website and in one of the section I want a simple layout as you can see here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mje86d9006xuceq/Capture.PNG?dl=0

I'm pretty sure I need to use javascript to vary the responses "today is (day)" and "10am til when". The responses are as follows:

Monday - Friday
10am til when

Saturday
9am til bike

Sunday
Maybe, maybe not

Can anyone write a simple script that would accomplish this, or point me in the right direction to do this?

I was told the following script would work, but I can't get it to even display on a web page... what am I doing wrong?

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay()
if(n == 6) {
    document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = "9am til bike";
} else if(!n) {
    document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = "Maybe, maybe not";
} else {
    document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = "10 am til when";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="lol"></p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [How do I display Day of Weed and vary responses by days?] Day of Weed?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong, that little snippet is correct, it could be improved with a switch statement, but overall look good.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqep6av09b83pxq/example.PNG -- this shows what the code itself looks like on the page. The image is washed out because dreamweaver is in the middle of crashing (stupid program) and I've added in the text "today is (DAY)" and "10am til when" myself so I could roughly format the rest of that section.

I need one bit of code that will say what day it is "Wednesday" or whatever and I need this to just display in a way that I can format it. I then need the second bit of code, which you've provided for me above but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...